# How to import NgbTime in Angular?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to import NgbTime in one of the components in my Angular application like this:
`import { NgbTime } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/timepicker/ngb-time';`

But I get an error : **Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/timepicker/ngb-time' in 'path-to-my-component'**

Whereas I was able to import NgbDate without any issues, like this:
`import { NgbDate } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';`

How to import NgbTime module ?

Comment: `import { NgbTimeStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';` you can use this instead.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda thanks, it worked.  Please move this to the Answer section, so that I can accept it as an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need this newer version to import

```
import { NgbTimeStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

This way you can get `NgbTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Developer answer, I needed to update my code from:

```
private myNgbTime = new NgbTime(12, 0, 0);
```

To

```
private myNgbTime: NgbTimeStruct = { hour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0 };
```